# Cloudformation For SG

Tags: amazon-vpc

need to create SG for mutiple VPCs using cloudformation with out hard coding vpc ids in SG
below is example with hard coded vpc but is there way u can get VPC id from mapping or anyother logic

```
MySecurityGroup:
     Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
     Properties:
       GroupDescription: My Security Group
       VpcId:
         - VpcId1
         - VpcId2
         - VpcId3
       SecurityGroupEgress:
         - IpProtocol: -1
           CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```